# Trouble with setting visibility of a group in a tablayout fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to use a switch to toggle the visibility of a group in constraint layout.  I keep getting an error on the setVisibility method that Android Studio "Cannot resolve method 'setVisibility(int)'."  I can figure out what I'm missing.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Switch;

import java.security.acl.Group;

public class FragmentCO2Settings extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;
private Group fractiongroup;
private Switch fractionswitch;

public static FragmentCO2Settings newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    FragmentCO2Settings fragment = new FragmentCO2Settings();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public FragmentCO2Settings() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.co2extractor_settings_fragment, container, false);
    fractionswitch = (Switch) getView().findViewById(R.id.fractswitch);
    fractiongroup = (Group) getView().findViewById(R.id.Fractiongroup);
    fractionswitch.setChecked(true);
    fractionswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                fractiongroup.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                fractiongroup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
    return rootView;

    }
}
```

The fractionswitch is set to checked by default and the fraction group set to visible.  I would like to set it so that when the fractionswitch is unclicked the fraction group will change visibility to GONE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
            if(isChecked){
                fractiongroup.setVisibility(ConstraintLayout.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                fractiongroup.setVisibility(ConstraintLayout.GONE);
            }
```

Or alternatively you can change the visibility of the referenced views individually.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I was using the Group class when I should have been using the ViewGroup class.  Changed that and it worked.